# Mercurial. Исключить все папки кроме одной через .hgignore

Tags: git, контроль-версий, mercurial

Имеется следующая структура каталогов:

```
assets
--dist
----css
----img
----upload
```

Необходимо через .hgignore исключить все папки, кроме upload, чтобы файлы dist и внутренних не попадали в коммит, а те, что в upload коммитились. Как это лучше всего сделать?
У меня пока исключена вся папка dist таким образом:

```
syntax: glob
assets/dist/*
```

Будет ли работать вот такой вариант - `!assets/dist/upload/*` ??? Если нет то как лучше всего поступить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `!<path>`это чистый гитизм, в hg не работает
2. Можно (но не нужно) использовать regexp типа

   `syntax: regex`

   `^path/(?!paths-that-you-want-not-to-ignore)`
3. Если вопрос об одном (или минимальном числе) исключении из общего игнорирования, то проще оставить одно простое правило и после руками один раз `hg add upload/**` (и повторять для новодобавленных файлов в upload)

Comment: Хорошо, а если например, у меня уже .hgignore наполнен правилами для syntax: glob, а я в конце файла поменяю syntax с glob на regex и напишу правило с помощью регулярки, это будет работать? Что то типа: `syntax: glob /assets/dist/* ... syntax: regex ^path/(?!paths-that-you-want-not-to-ignore)`

Comment: @unreal_serg - будет. Различные синтаксисы вообще можно смешивать в произвольном порядке, если каждую секцию отбивать правильным `syntax`

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделал!